# Заполнить две таблицы в БД

Tags: sql

[image: БД]

Вопрос такой. Как заполнить две таблицы сразу?

Comment: ни как. только по очереди, сначала вставляете запись в родительскую таблицу, получаете id вставленной записи и вставляете в дочернюю

Comment: использовать мульти запрос ?

Comment: Хранимой процедурой.

Comment: @bobyliov.seryozha С точки зрения sql никаких мультизапросов не бывает. каждый запрос сам по себе. Если нужна атомарность операции - используйте транзакции. Если нужно сделать за один вызов, то хранимые процедуры, триггера на view (если ваша БД такое поддерживает) и прочие подобные средства. Если вдруг у вас postgresql, то там можно таки в одном CTE запросе